# how to get WMI events?

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, wmi-query, hyper-v

How to list the WMI events registered to Msvm_ComputerSystem class. I have created a vm and have an event to registerpoweronEvent. now i want to list the events registered. please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `ObjectQuery` class

```
            VMState vmState = VMState.Undefined;
            var connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            connectionOptions.Username = userName;
            connectionOptions.Password = password;

            var managementScope= new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\virtualization", hostServer), connectionOptions );
            manScope.Connect();  

            var objectQuery= new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem");
            var managementObjectSearcher  = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, objectQuery);
            var collection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

            foreach (var managementObject  in collection )
            {
               Console.WriteLine(managementObject["Yourkey"].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: I tried tis code but I am getting the following exception: Exception.System.Management.ManagementException was unhandled  HResult=-2146233087 not found. And I did't get why u are using VMState.